# Django - Forms - assign custom attributes to forms in forms.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

The question title might be a little misleading, but I couldn't think of a better title. If you've got better title, please edit the title.

I have following set of `models.py` and forms.py`

```
# models.py
class BHA_Component(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    field_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    field_3 = models.CharField(max_length=100)

# forms.py
class BHA_Component_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        fields = '__all__'
```

I want to create custom attributes for each field, so that I can identify what kind of field it is on the Front-End, and assign a class for each field type.

Something like this:

[image]

Some fields are just plain blank, some are grey, some are purple, and some have check boxes. These are done by manually giving each field a particular HTML class on the Front-End. However, I want to give each field some attributes on the Back-End, and have those attributes identified on the Front-End. So, something like this:

```
{% for field in bha_component_form %}

  {% if field.custom_attribute == 'option_1' %}
    {{ field|add_class:"has_checkbox"}}
  {% else if field.custom_attribute == 'option_2' %}
    {{ field|add_class:"blue_background"}}
  {% else %}
    {{ field|add_class:"plain"}}
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass in attributes on the backend you can try something likes this:

```
email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': "form_control form-control-lg", 'placeholder': "Email"}), required=True, )
```

So, for your specific case:

`models.py`:

```
class BHA_Component(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'custom_attribute': "option_1") })
    field_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'custom_attribute': "option_2") })
    field_3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput() })
```

It should be a case of using something like this in your template:

```
{% for field in bha_component_form %}
  {% if field.widget.attrs.custom_attribute == 'option_1' %}
    {{ field|add_class:"has_checkbox"}}
  {% else if field.widget.attrs.custom_attribute == 'option_2' %}
    {{ field|add_class:"blue_background"}}
  {% else %}
    {{ field|add_class:"plain"}}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

It should just be a case of modifying what I have outlined above for your specific use case.

Hope that helps!